# Why didn't Mon-El land at the same time as Superman?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

I'm confused about how Mon-El's arrival time from Daxam to Earth makes sense.

He leaves Daxam as a result of Krypton's explosion at much the same time as Superman (Kal-El) and Supergirl (Kara Zor-El).

Kar was obviously sucked into the Phantom Zone which explain why she arrived so much later than her cousin but if Mon-El and Superman leave Daxam And Krypton respectively at the same time **why does Mon-El land on earth in 2016 instead of 1982?**

Comment: We know that the travel time isn't significant, hence no aging.

Comment: I don't think the "timeline" added anything to the question. I've rephrased it as a sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Says [here](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Mon-El#Landing_on_Earth) that the answer is in Season 2, Episode 1 - "The Adventures of Supergirl":

> The pod travelled passing The Well of Stars (a region in space where time is ceased) and got stuck there for decades, before eventually finding its way to Earth, where it crash-landed.

Basically he got stuck in a place with no time, hence the "no ageing" thing, and he only got out of it after ~30 Earth years before travelling the rest of the way to Earth.

It's a bit of a fudge in terms of writing, but there's your answer.

Comment: Kinda wish that there was something more to it but thanks for the answer it makes sense again.

Comment: This is also the 3rd use of an area of space where time is halted/slowed (the first 2 being The Vanishing Point from legends and the Phantom Zone)

Answer (score 3):

This was addressed in the first episode of Season 2. Winn decrypts Mon-El's flight-recorder and they find that he was trapped in a region of space (known as the ["Well of Stars"](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Well_of_Stars)) where time doesn't flow normally.

> **Winn:** *Now, it seems sleeping beauty on his journey from Krypton passed through something called the ...* [pauses slightly] *"Segara
> Beyal"*
>
> **Kara:** *The Well of Stars. My father took me there once. Time doesn't pass there. So that's why he's still so young.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Supergirl: The Adventure of Supergirl - Transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=297&t=28987)</sup></sub>

[image]