# How old are Rhea and Lor-Gand?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

Following up from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155391/why-didnt-mon-el-land-at-the-same-time-as-superman) I started to wonder how old Mon-El's parents are:

We know Mon-El was stuck in the *Well of Stars* for some unknown amount of time, which is why he didn't age significantly - in fact we see him on Daxam and he looks just the same. So he seems to be in his 20s (as is Chris Wood with 29).

We also know that he left Daxam *34 years* before he arrived (2016 - Season 1 finale / Season 2 opening) as the title card from the Season 2 Finale (2017 - one year after his arrival) gives us a clear point in time when Krypton exploded:

[image]

Furthermore, the ages of the actors playing Queen Rhea (Teri Hatcher is 52) and King Lor-Gand (Kevin Sorbo is 58) are known and we are shown that the characters are surprised when they arrive in the Sol system and discover that they feel different and stronger due to the yellow sun.

Additionally they talk about having been searching for Mon-El all these years, so I think *suspended animation* can be ruled out (but I might be mistaken there).

Finally it is no secret that Daxamites are promiscous, but still, how could a pair of 50-60 year old people have had a 20-something son 34 years ago?

Comment: Why do we assume that the actors ages have anything to do with the characters ages?

Comment: @Paulie_D Because under their natural sun they would most likely age as humans do on Earth and characters on tv or in movies -- at least to me -- are always roughly supposed to be the age they are shown to be (unless explicitly stated otherwise), it is a visual medium after all. But it would of course be the answer if there can be found any indication that they are in fact in their 80s or 90s.

Comment: "*Because under their natural sun they would most likely age as humans do on Earth*" Is there precedent of this regarding Kryptonites/Daxamites, or is this just an assumption? My knowledge of Superman lore is not very extensive.

Comment: @phantom42 It is an assumption, but I believe a founded one because if it were not the case Superman's "Kryptonians age at a much slower rate *here on Earth*" in episode 2x01 wouldn't make much sense. He would have omitted the "here on Earth" bit if they aged slower period, wouldn't he?

Comment: Fair enough. Didn't recall that bit.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing saying they weren't in suspended animation part (or even most) of the time. When it was first shown that the Daxamites had a lead on Mon-El being on Earth (although it wasn't known to be Daxamites to the audience), Rhea and Lar-Gand weren't seen. Given the ship had been searching for Mon-El for decades, and the other Daxamites didn't look particularly elderly either, either Daxamites are long-lived and the crew didn't physically age significantly, or possibly most of the crew were in some kind of stasis at any given time and with a small number of them on active duty rotation. In fact, they may have woken both the king and queen up at the same time just because they had located him.